# Building a username search by writing custom module

Tags: 7, forms

My module simply allows a user to type in a user ID # in a field and hit the submit button.  The page should return the username.

```
function usersearch_form_submit($form,&$form_state) {
  $query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE uid = :uid";
  $result = db_query($query,array(':uid' => $form_state['values']['uid']));
  foreach($result as $user) {
    echo "The username is $user<br>";
  }
  $form_state['rebuild'] =  TRUE;
}
```

Nothing really happens after I hit the submit button.  I get sent back to the form as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form submission handler doesn't use `echo` to output its result. You need to use a render array to render the result, such as with the following code. I assume `usersearch_form()` is the form builder function.

```
function usersearch_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // Add the form elements.

  if (!empty($form_state['username'])) {
    $form['username'] = array(
      '#markup' => t('The username is %username', array('%username' => $form_state['username']))
    );
  }

  return $form;
}

function usersearch_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $username = db_query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE uid = :uid', array(':uid' => $form_state['values']['uid']))->fetchField();

  $form_state['username'] = $username;
  $form_state['rebuild'] =  TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.  What I was banging my head on was that I was trying to do print_r($result), but I would never see any output!  Somehow Drupal seems to overpower my $result variable.  Anyhow, once I did $user->username, then it appeared, but as you mentioned, it was not rendered correctly.  I just was frustrated since I could not use print_r($result) to check the output and I thought the db_query was returning blanks.